# How to get multi-dimensional array of input fields with jQuery as array

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays

jQuery find() and children() give the array of all the matching criteria. 
The array is single dimensional.
But I need to generate an multi-dimensional array to have the inputs in the child container.

Just need  little hint, how can i achieve this efficiently, rather then looping the children and generating the multi-dimensional array.

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
    var inputs = $('.container .box').find('input');
    // var inputs = $('.container .box :input')
    console.log( inputs );
    /*  This will result as follow, 
        [
            0: input.tag_name
            1: input.tag_name
            2: input.tag_name
            3: input.tag_name
            4: input.tag_name
        ]
        But i need the following nested array
        [
            0: input.tag_name
            1: input.tag_name
                [
                2: input.tag_name
                    [
                    3: input.tag_name            
                    ]
                ]
            4: input.tag_name

        ]
    */
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
    <div class="row box">
        <input type="text=" value="1" class="tag_name" />
    </div>
    <div class="row box">
        <input type="text=" value="2" class="tag_name" />
        <div class="box">
            <input type="text=" value="2.1" class="tag_name" />
            <div class="box">
                <input type="text=" value="2.1.1" class="tag_name" />
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
        <div class="row box">
        <input type="text=" value="3" class="tag_name" />
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I don't think you can do it without manipulating the inputs result.

Comment: you have to loop the children

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using function recursion to dig as deep as is necessary to collect the nested input elements and returning arrays along the way to maintain the nested structure:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    function boxindexes(self) {
        var bi = [];
        bi.push(self.children('input')[0]);
        self.children('.box').each(function(){
            bi.push(boxindexes($(this)));
        });
        return bi;
    }
    var inputs = [];
    $('.container').children('.box').each(function() {
        inputs.push(boxindexes($(this)));
    });
    console.log( inputs );
});
```

Outputs:

```
[
  0: [0: input.tag_name],
  1: [
       0: input.tag_name,
       1: [
            0: input.tag_name,
            1: [0: input.tag_name]
          ]
     ],
  2: [0 input.tag_name]
]
```

See for yourself: http://jsfiddle.net/BloodyKnuckles/a0j0xyun/